# The Final Question of MU episode 1

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, encoded-message

I played [this](http://www.kongregate.com/games/StudioCime/mu-complex-episode-one) puzzle game, the last question of which leads to [this](http://mu.database.studiocime.com/) website, which contains, hidden as a comment in its HTML, the following string:

> OgUMGU0EHk0ZBQwZTQMCBB4ITSwqLCQjUgo=

Believing this to be a base64 encoding, I decoded it and got

> : MM MM,*,$#R

Where the first character is `:` and each M is preceded by one or more control characters.  I'm stumped on what to do with the string at this point, and am unsure base64 decoding was the right choice.

Comment: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=110384&p=3686054

Comment: @skv Do you want to pull that out into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=110384&p=3686054), you have to

> XOR all bytes by 0x6d

to get

> What is that noise AGAIN?g